# Unable to add RestSharp as reference into Visual Studio 2019

Tags: c#, restsharp

I have created a console C# application to call REST API to send data to the external application using RESTSHARP. NuGet.Framework package is added to the solution but unable to add RESTSHARP as reference. Can anyone give any input on this to resolve the issue?

[image]

Comment: How did you add the package to the "solution" (project I hope) and why can't you add a reference? What exactly is happening on your screen?

Comment: Step 1 : I have created a C# console application followed by adding nuget.frameworks by right clicking on the project and "Manage nuget packages" option. Step 2: I am trying to add RESTSHARP as reference using same navigation as step 1 but not getting anything in the list to add related to RestSharp.

Comment: You don't have to; NuGet packages' contents are added as references automatically.

Comment: Ok. Then can you please share the steps to add RestSharp as reference to the project

Comment: I just explained that you don't need to, because installing the NuGet package will already do this for you. What are you trying to do and what doesn't work? Do you need a `using` directive to import a namespace in code?

Comment: While I am using directive "using RestSharp" within the code then it is showing error "The type or namespace name 'RestSharp' could not be found".

Comment: Do you have any warnings or errors in Visual Studio's Error List? Please [edit] your question to include them, and show a screenshot of the project in the Solution Explorer, with the "Packages" node expanded.

Comment: Which of your two projects did you install the RestSharp nuget into? It does not show up in the Packages list of **ExternalWebServiceConsumpTest**, but that's where you're trying to use it, isn't it?

Comment: Yes, true. I installed NuGet.Frameworks as available but didn't find anything to install related to RestSharp. Could you please help me on this?

Answer (score 0):

You installed the wrong nuget. You don't need the *NuGet.Frameworks* package, that's unrelated to your needs.

You need to add the [RestSharp nuget](https://www.nuget.org/packages/RestSharp) to your *ExternalWebServiceConsumpTest* project

To do so, please do the following:

1. Right click on your *ExternalWebServiceConsumpTest* project
2. Then click "Manage NuGet Packages"
3. Make sure the Package Source is set to "nuget.org"
4. In the search bar, type RestSharp and hit enter
5. Select the RestSharp package and install it to your *ExternalWebServiceConsumpTest* project

[image]

Now, your code should be able to find the `RestSharp` namespace

Comment: I am not getting RestSharp in the list

Comment: Can you show the content your .csproj file (right-click, then "Edit Project File")? What is your TargetFramework?

Comment: <Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <OutputType>Exe</OutputType>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
  </PropertyGroup>

</Project>

Comment: Okay, that should be compatible. Is "nuget.org" set as the *Package Source*? See this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/consume-packages/install-use-packages-visual-studio#find-and-install-a-package

Comment: Package source has been changed to nuget.org. Now RestSharp package is available in the list and installed successfully.

Comment: Great. Please, kindly upvote and accept my answer then, if this solved your problem.